# crash inside vp8_short_fdct8x4_neon (libvpx 1.2.0) while building for iOS in PIE mode using xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, libvpx

Here I configured libvpx 1.2.0 for iOS using below mentioned configuration command

./configure --target=armv7-darwin-gcc --sdk-path=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
--libc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/

and vpx_version was showing:

## define VERSION_STRING      " v1.2.0"

I used necessary VP8 source files for running on iOS devices in PIE mode and made settings using xcode 4.5.VP8 is working fine for multi-thread (g_thread > 1)when I build on xcode 4.6 and xcode 5.0 but when I build using xcode 4.5, it was crashing inside vp8_short_fdct8x4_neon assembly code when I set g_thread more than one. xcode 4.5 is using  LLVM APPLE 4.1 compiler and is compiled and static lib is created correctly.

My problem is why with xcode 4.5, for g_thread = 1, vp8 is running fine and why its crashing when I set more than threads. Is there anything we are doing wrong configuring and building vp8 in xcode 4.5 version.

Thank you and Regards
Girish Bale